# Getting blob image back to file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blob, multipartform-data

I am having problem converting image to blob and back to file, I mean when I convert image to blob and display on the page, chose which I want to keep and which I want to remove and after try to convert back to file and append to form data, nothing gets appended to `formData` and file type and size on new files from blob images are different, how can I change that? Thank you

```js
$(document).on('click', '#addProduct', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var arr = [];
   for(var q=0; q<$('.image-buttons').length; q++) {
    var blob = $('.image-buttons').children('img').attr('src');
    var fileOfBlob = new File([blob], 'image'+q);
    arr.push(fileOfBlob);
   }
  if(arr.length < 4 && arr.length > 0){
   var formData = new FormData();

   $.each(arr, function(i, file) {
       formData.append('images', file);
       console.log(file);
   });
   
   console.log(formData);
   return false;
  }
 });

 $(document).on('change', '#images', function() {
  var reg = /\.(gif|jpg|png|GIF|JPG|PNG|jpeg|JPEG)$/i;
  var imageNameArray = [];
  for(var j = 0; j<$("#images")[0].files.length; j++) {
   if(!$("#images")[0].files[j].name.match(reg)){
    imageNameArray.push($("#images")[0].files[j].name);
   }
  }
  if(imageNameArray.length === 0 && $("#images")[0].size<2097152){
   for(var e=0; e<$("#images")[0].files.length; e++) {
    $('.img-button-holder').append('<div class="image-buttons"><img src="'+window.URL.createObjectURL($("#images")[0].files[e])+'"><div class="img-tools"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-times removeImg" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div>');
   }
   $('.image-display').append('<img src="'+window.URL.createObjectURL($("#images")[0].files[0])+'">');
  }
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.image-buttons', function() {
  var this_img = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
  $('.image-buttons').css('border','1px solid #e0e0e0');
  $(this).css('border','2px solid red');
  $('.image-display').children('img').attr('src', this_img);
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.img-tools > .fa', function() {
  var this_el = $(this).parent().parent();
  if($(this).hasClass('removeImg')){
   $(this_el).remove();
  }else if($(this).hasClass('fa-angle-double-left')) {
   var prev = $(this_el).prev();
   $(this_el).insertBefore(prev);
  }else if($(this).hasClass('fa-angle-double-right')) {
   var next = $(this_el).next();
   $(this_el).insertAfter(next);
  }
 });
```

```css
.addNew {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 float: left;
}

.addNew > form {
 width: 40%;
 float: left;
 height: auto;
 margin-right: 5%;
}

.addNew > .image-display {
 width: 55%;
 float: right;
 min-height: 300px;
 height: auto;
 border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
 position: relative;
}

.addNew .image-buttons {
 width: 30%;
 height: 80px;
 margin: 10px 1.5%;
 border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.img-button-holder {
 width: 55%;
 float: right;
}

.image-buttons > img, .image-display > img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
}

.image-display > img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 min-height: auto;
 min-width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0; left: 0;
}

.img-tools {
 color: red;
 font-size: 2rem;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 top: 0; left: 0;
}

.img-tools > i {
 float: left;
 width: 30%;
 margin: 5px 1.5%;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addNew">
<form>
<input type="file" name="images" id="images" multiple>
<button id="addProduct">Add</button>
</form>

<div class="image-display"></div>
<div class="img-button-holder"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: One thing needing fixing is that you're appending only a single member to the FormData object. The name of the member should be changed on every round of the loop. You might also want to pass a different file name for the each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A blobURI (that you miscalled `blob` in your code) is just a string.
The File object you create is just that string in a text/plain file.

You don't have to convert from a File to a blobURI to a File.

Just keep the initial Files, store them in a good ol' Array, manage them from there.

Create the blobURI only to display these Files (it's really just a pointer in the memory so your document (here `<img>`) knows how to access the file on the user disk, and hence can't be shared).

When you need to send the files, simoly take them from the Array you did the management with.

*ps: Note that depending on your back-end, you might have to append a `[]` at the name of your formData key.*

```js
function sendToServer() {

  var formData = new FormData(),
    files = fileHandler.list; // grab them directly from our manager
  // it's an Array, so use Array methods
  files.forEach(function(file) {
    // since you are on php, to be able to append multiple items in the same field,
    // you need to append '[]' at the end of your fieldName
    formData.append('images[]', file);
  });
  // send it to your server
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'your_php_script');
  // xhr.send(formData);
  // but from SO we will just show what's inside
  if (typeof formData.getAll === 'function') {
    console.log(formData.getAll('images[]'));
  }

}
// A basic file manager which will expose its selected files in an Array
function FileHandler(options) {
  if (!options || typeof options !== 'object')
    options = {};

  this.options = options;
  // this is really the only important part: we use an Array to store all our files
  this.list = [];

  this.addButton = isValidElement(options.addButton) || $('<button>', {
    text: 'Add new Files'
  });
  // also, we use a single file input
  this.input = $('<input>', $.extend(options.input || {}, {
    type: 'file',
    class: 'fh-input',
    multiple: true,
  }));

  this.items_container = isValidElement(options.items_container) || $('<div>', {
    class: 'fh-item-container'
  });

  this.preview = this.initPreview();

  this.addButton.on('click', function() {
    this.input.click()
  }.bind(this));
  this.input.on('change', this.onchange.bind(this));

  this.items_container.on('click', '.fh-item .fh-remove', this.remove.bind(this));
  this.items_container.on('click', '.fh-item :not(.fh-remove)', this.handleItemClick.bind(this));
  this.items_container.on('load', 'img', revokeURL);

  // We don't need blobURIs for anything else than loading <img> elements,
  // so we can revoke them directly at load
  function revokeURL(evt) {
    var url = evt.currentTarget.src;
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }

  function isValidElement(obj) {
    var $obj = $(obj);
    return $obj[0] && $obj[0] instanceof Element && $obj.eq(0);
  }
}
FileHandler.prototype = Object.create({
  add: function addFile(file) {
    if (!(file instanceof Blob))
      throw new TypeError('Argument 1 must be Blob or a File');
    var $item = this.generateItem(file);
    this.items_container.append($item);
    // store it in our Array
    this.list.push(file);
    this.preview.show(file);
    return $item;
  },
  remove: function removeFile(event) {
    var $target = $(event.currentTarget),
      $item = $target.parents('.fh-item').eq(0),
      file = $item.data('fh.file'),
      index = this.list.indexOf(file);

    $item.remove();
    if (index > -1) {
      // remove it from our Array
      this.list.splice(index, 1);
    }

    if (this.preview.current === file) {
      if (this.list.length) {
        var next = index <= (this.list.length - 1) ? index : 0;
        this.preview.show(this.list[next]);
      } else this.preview.hide();
    }
  },
  generateItem: function generateItem(file) {
    if (!(file instanceof Blob))
      throw new TypeError('Argument 1 must be Blob or a File');
    var $cont = $('<div>', {
        class: 'fh-item'
      }),
      $title = $('<span>', {
        text: file.name || 'unknown-file (' + file.type + ')',
        class: 'fh-file_name'
      }),
      $btn = $('<button>', {
        class: 'fh-remove',
        text: 'x',
        title: 'remove',
        name: 'remove item'
      }),
      $thumb = $('<div>', {
        class: 'fh-thumb'
      })
      // a single time blobURI
      .append($('<img>', {
        src: URL.createObjectURL(file)
      }));

    $cont.data('fh.file', file);

    return $cont.append(
      $title,
      $btn,
      $thumb
    );
  },
  onchange: function oninputchange(evt) {
    // retrieve the Files contained in our single input
    var fileList = this.input[0].files;
    for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
      this.add(fileList[i]);
    }
  },
  handleItemClick: function handleItemClick(evt) {
    var $target = $(evt.currentTarget),
      $item = $target.parents('.fh-item').eq(0),
      file = $item.data('fh.file');
    this.preview.show(file);
  },
  initPreview: function() {
    var $cont = $('<div>', {
        class: 'fh-preview'
      }),
      img = new Image();

    return {
      container: $cont.append(img),
      update: function updatePreview(url) {},
      show: function show(file) {
        if (!(file instanceof Blob)) {
          console.warn('Not a Blob', file);
          throw new TypeError('Argument 1 must be Blob or a File');
        }
        if (this.current !== file) {
          this.current = file;
          img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        }
        $cont.show();
      },
      hide: function hide() {
        img.src = '#';
        $cont.hide();
      }

    };
  }

});


var fileHandler = new FileHandler({
  input: {
    accept: 'image/*'
  }
});
$('body').append(
  fileHandler.addButton,
  $('<button>', {
    text: 'send to server'
  })
  .on('click', sendToServer),
  fileHandler.items_container,
  fileHandler.preview.container,
);
```

```css
.fh-item {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 130px;
  min-height: 130px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.fh-file_name {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin: 2px 4px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.fh-remove {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fh-remove:hover {
  color: #CC0000;
}

.fh-thumb {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.fh-thumb>img {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did that and when I append all images to formData as:
$.each(images, function(i, file) {
 formData.append('images[]', file);
}); On php side I have mixed arrays first array is name, second is type etc. How should I add one file as one array not like 4 files names in one array 4 types in another..?

Comment: @StupidKid I added a full example

Comment: I did it already, now I have different problem with cookies on phone(android) cookies won't set but they are allowed by browser... btw i will accept ur answer since it moved me in right direction but my solution was different :D